# How to detect "long press" in Elm?

Tags: elm

Is there a way to detect a "long press" in Elm?  i.e. a mouse/pointer down event followed by a period of time without movement (or at least no movement across an element boundary).

I am using the elm package mpizenberg/elm-touch-events.

I have found discussion of doing this in javascript, but not in Elm.

Thanks

Ivan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

1. Track how long the button has been pressed -- initialize it as "not pressed", represented by `Nothing`
2. When the button is pressed, update the model to show the button has been pressed for 0 seconds (`Just 0`)
3. Use a `Time.every` subscription to increment the 'pressed time' every second or so
4. After every increment, check how long the button has been pressed, and do something if it's been long enough

You would need to track this state in your model for every element that can be "long pressed".

Full example: https://ellie-app.com/wRngKVN6Gca1

I'm not familiar with the mpizenberg/elm-touch-events package, but I think you could adapt this code to use the package without too much trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that's a good idea - and thanks for the working example, very clear!  I've also successfully tried a different method (suggested by mpizenberg of mpizenberg/elm-touch-events) where a mouse down triggers a ```Task.perform (always MaybeLongPress) (Process.sleep 1500)```. I'll post working code this week and link from here.

Comment: Actually I think your idea is better.  It's more robust, checking that the mouse is down for a continuous period of time.